# Excel cell change value dilemma

Tags: excel

I have a cell that has a function linked with Bloomberg, and it obtains live tick data. I would like to trigger a calculation when the cell values changes, and in the meantime I want to save the last value to another cell so that I can replay it later.

For example: the cell right now has a value 20, and then it changes to 21. I want to use the 21 for calulations while saving the value of 20 to another cell.

I guess we could work in the worksheetchange, now I'm facing a dilemma that if the cell changes, I can no longer record the last value, 20, but can only record the latest value, 21.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should use VBA, with the worksheet change event. And don't wait till the value changes to save the "old" value, but save that value the second it changed, so that you can store it as old, whilst it is still "live".

Comment: good point >.< thanks thanks.